# C Line Reading Suddenly Stops

Tags: c, csv, pointers

I am reading a .csv file with:

```
FILE * fPointer; = fopen(fileName, "r");
char singleLineContent[150];

while(fgets(singleLineContent, 150, fPointer))
{
     /* data handling */
}
```

It stops reading the file at line 40239. I have no idea why.

Here is the entire file. It returns -1. There are over 1 million lines in the file. I also write another file with this data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Type the name of a file to be read (30 character max): ");
    char fileName[30];
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    printf("Type the name of destination file (30 character max): ");
    char fileNameW[30];
    scanf("%s", fileNameW);
    FILE * fPointerForWriting = fopen(fileNameW, "w");
    FILE * fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen(fileName, "r");

    int i = 1;
    char singleLineContent[150];

    while(fgets(singleLineContent, 150, fPointer))
    {
        char *token = strtok(singleLineContent, ",\n");
        fprintf(fPointerForWriting, "%d", atoi(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
        fprintf(fPointerForWriting, ",%d     %d\n", atoi(token), i);
        if(token == NULL)
        {
            printf("There are no tokens\n");
            return -3;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fPointerForWriting);
    fclose(fPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code.

Comment: It returns zero? It crashes? It steps out for a cigarette?

Comment: `FILE * fPointer; = fopen(fileName, "r");` does not compile.

Comment: Likely lines at/near #40239 are long, unexpectedly formated, UTF code, etc.  Post lines 40239-5 to 40239+5.  Post more code.

Comment: The code you have posted is not the same code you were able to run:  `FILE * fPointer>>>;<<< = fopen(fileName, "r");`

Comment: Is the file all text?  If this is a Windows file it could have a ^Z (control+Z) character in it which indicates end-of-file.

Comment: An obvious question:  how many lines are in the file?  (I hope it is more than 40239)

Comment: It returns -1. There are over 1 million lines in the file.

Comment: 1) Change code.  Do not attempt `fprintf(fPointerForWriting, ",%d     %d\n", atoi(token), i);` if `token == NULL`.  2) When `token == NULL` occurs, print `singleLineContent`

Comment: @ThomasBirrings What is the purpose of the last paragraph in your question? You are just repeating the same line and we don't know if that is part of your text file or an unecessary comment.

Comment: You need to add more details that are not code. It is saying you need to add more details that are not code.

Comment: when calling scanf with a format string of "%s",  the input will halt when encountering any white space.  a new line is white space.  the newline is not consumed by the scanf (as currently written).  so the second scanf will allways fail as no characters will be input.  Suggest always checking the returned value from scanf(), not the parameters, to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: 'fprintf(fPointerForWriting, ",%d     %d\n", atoi(token), i);', if 'token' contains NULL, will cause a seg fault event.  Always check for NULL before doing anything with a value returned from strtok()

Answer (score 3):

You should be more careful reading filenames from `stdin`: `scanf` may cause a buffer overflow if you type more than 29 characters. Even 30 characters as you mention in the prompt is one too many. Use this format:

```
scanf("%29s", fileName);
```

This will prevent a potential undefined behaviour, but you should add appropriate checks for error cases such as end of file by testing the return value.  Furthermore, `scanf` is a very poor API to read a filename, it will stop at the first white space character, which is alas common in filename these days.

A better solution to read the filenames would be:

```
fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);
fileName[strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Similarly, you should check if the files could be open successfully.

Finally, if you read a line with fewer than 2 numbers at the beginning, your parser will fail to detect that and invoke undefined behaviour:

```
    char *token = strtok(singleLineContent, ",\n");
    fprintf(fPointerForWriting, "%d", atoi(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    fprintf(fPointerForWriting, ",%d     %d\n", atoi(token), i);
    if(token == NULL)
    {
        printf("There are no tokens\n");
        return -3;
    }
```

If `token` is `NULL`, `atoi(token)` invokes undefined behaviour: it may well crash your program with an exit code of `-1`.

Add proper tests like this:

```
    if (!strchr(singleLineContent, '\n')) {
        printf("line %d too long: %s\n", i, singleLineContent);
    }
    char *token = strtok(singleLineContent, ",\n");
    if (token == NULL) {
        printf("No numbers at line %d\n", i);
        return -3;
    }
    fprintf(fPointerForWriting, "%d", atoi(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    if(token == NULL) {
        printf("Missing number at line %d\n", i);
        return -3;
    }
    fprintf(fPointerForWriting, ",%d     %d\n", atoi(token), i);
```

Comment: It runs half as well now. Now it only processes 20,000 lines.

Comment: @Thomas Birrings: You might have lines with no numbers at all.  I edited the answer.

Comment: @Thomas Birrings Posting the last lines of output with the `"No numbers at line ...` or `"Missing number  ...` woudl be useful.

Comment: @chux The last lines of output are just normal lines. There is never an indication anything goes wrong.

Comment: @chux: I know, I am a fervent promoter of `strcspn()`.

Comment: @Thomas Birrings:  Given you are parsing a `csv` file, it is unlikely to have misformated lines, but you may have lines longer than 149 characters that will be read in more than one step, effectively triggering the error cases.  Make the buffer larger.

Comment: @Thomas Birrings Interesting.  Including a `printf("Success\n\n");` at the end of code would help differentiate true success versus an unusual exit.

Comment: @chux I did that just now and it prints success. The program is finishing, it;s just not reading the entire file. Weird.

Comment: @Thomas Birrings Look at the .csv for the previous few lines that last passed in your code and also note the following lines (suggest posting them). chqrlie on the right track here.  Suspect a Control-Z or illegal UTF char or something in the .csv file.  Good luck

Comment: @Thomas Birrings: Or just share the whole csv file, there is something fishy going on.

Comment: -- if you do, post it into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)! We don't need your 1 million lines of text in your post. Not even if they *all* say  "It says I need to add more details that are not code. It says I need to add more details that are not code."

Comment: @Jongware: I would think the fine folks at SO do not allow posting a million lines in a question... But I did not try.

Comment: @chqrlie: apologies, I obviously meant to warn the OP only. Hope he sees it anyway. Maybe he's thinking about how many details to add that are not CSV.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the program halts when the OS output buffer gets full, and the OS tries to write to a file with no name.

see my comment about using scanf() and white space